# jQuery - Animate Elements Positioning

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, jquery-animate

How do I get the jQuery listed below to animate properly?

```
var search = $('.searchField');
var searchButton = $('.searchSubmit');

search.on('focus', function() {
    search.animate({
        'right':'auto',
        'left':'0'
    }, 600);
    searchButton.animate({
        'right':'0',
        'left':'auto'
    }, 600);
});
search.on('focusout', function() {
    search.animate({
        'right':'0',
        'left':'auto'
    }, 600);
    searchButton.animate({
        'right':'auto',
        'left':'0'
    }, 600);
});
```

Ideally, I would like the `searchButton` to go from left to right, on `:focus`, switching places with `search`. I am using animate in attempt to have the two elements "slide" into their new positioning, rather than having the elements jump from one side to the next.

Currently, the `searchButton` doesn't go to the right on `:focus`, and the `search` element jumps to positioning left, rather than having a "slide" effect.

[For the live jsFiddle, click here.](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwierzba/u97jkeq1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it makes sense to use simple CSS transition:

```
.searchField {
    /* ... */
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transition: all .6s ease;
    &:focus {
        /* ... */
        right: 50px;
        &+.searchSubmit {
            left: 100%;
            margin-left: -50px;
        }
    }
}
```

Also remove `</input>`, input elements are self-closing tags: `<input />`.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u97jkeq1/8/

Comment: Thanks for the `<input />` reminder. This solution works easy enough.

Comment: Nice, I never knew about putting psuedo classes in the selectors  &:active. +1

Comment: @Billy Note, that this is SASS, not pure CSS :)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, that would have had me scratching my head for a while

Answer (score 2):

I actually believe @dfsq answer is better, to do it in CSS. But I wanted to fix the original code and to give other people using your question the choice of approach.

**DEMO:** [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u97jkeq1/13/)

**JS**

```
var search = $('.searchField');
var searchButton = $('.searchSubmit');
var searchWidth = $('.searchField').innerWidth();
var searchButtonWidth = $('.searchSubmit').innerWidth();

var searchContainer = searchWidth + searchButtonWidth;

$('#search').css({ width: searchContainer });

search.on('focus', function() {
    search.animate({
        'right':'auto',
        'left':'-10'
    }, 400);
    searchButton.animate({
        'right':'0',
        'left':'400'
    }, 400);
});
search.on('focusout', function() {
    search.animate({
        'right':'0',
        'left':'50'
    }, 400);
    searchButton.animate({
        'right':'auto',
        'left':'0'
    }, 400);
});

searchButton.mouseover(function() {
    $('.searchIcon').css('opacity', '0.5');
});
searchButton.mouseout(function() {
    $('.searchIcon').css('opacity', '1');
});

search.bind('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        searchButton.click();
    };
});

searchButton.click(function() {
    search.val(''); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I used marginRight/marginLeft to animate them vs. using right/left positioning.

I like that you're using right/left positioning, but for this case, it's easier to use margin-left. If you use right/left positioning, you will also have to update your css.

Another option is to set a class with javascript and use css transitions for animating (like you did with the opacity).

```
search.on('focus', function() {
  search.animate({
    marginRight: "50"
  }, 600);

  searchButton.animate({
    marginLeft: "450"
  }, 600);
});

search.on('focusout', function() {
  search.animate({
    marginRight: "0"
  }, 600);
  searchButton.animate({
    marginLeft: "0"
  }, 600);
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u97jkeq1/9/)